# Setting vertex attributes from a data frame in a large network

Tags: r, igraph

I want to set vertex attributes in a large network (20k nodes). For simplicity here is a sample of the edgelist:

```
library(igraph)
el <- matrix( c(1, 2,1,3,1,4,2,3,2,5,3,6,3,7,3,8,3,9,12,13,13,14 ), nc = 2, byrow = TRUE)
el[,1] = as.character(el[,1])
el[,2] = as.character(el[,2])
g = graph.data.frame(el,directed=FALSE)
```

Also, I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
ID = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,NA,NA)
Attr1 = c(12,13,14,NA,14,13,16,NA,24,13,15) 
Attr2 = c(NA, "bb", "cc","ff","dd",NA,"hh",NA,"kk","dd","cc") 
Attributes = data.frame(ID, Attr1, Attr2)
rm(Attr1)
rm(Attr2)
rm(ID)
```

I want to use the data from the Attributes data frame as vertex attributes. As in the example, some of the data is missing (e.g. some vertices in the network are not represented in the Attributes data frame). The number of rows in the data frame matches the number of vertices.
I want to add the attributes using the ID for matching  (the IDs in the edgelist and the Attributes dataframe are mostly the same, however some IDs are only in either the edgelist or the dataframe).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`set_vertex_attr` will do this

Updating answer so that names and values are taken from the dataframe

```
for(cn in colnames(Attributes)) {
    g = set_vertex_attr(g, cn,  1:nrow(Attributes), value=Attributes[,cn])
}
```

Comment: This solution does work, but it does not refer to the data frame that I created but to the values. I will update my question. Thank you!

Comment: @PCK1992 Answer updated to make use of whatever is in the data.frame

Comment: I tried this solution and I am not entirely sure if I used the code correctly. I tried to specify my problem again. Does this solution use the ID in both the edgelist and the Attributes dataframe to match the attributes?

Answer (score 1):

there is a fast way to set attribute, you can consider.

```
V(g)$ID <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,NA,NA)
V(g)$Attr1 <- c(12,13,14,NA,14,13,16,NA,24,13,15) 
V(g)$Attr2 <- c(NA, "bb", "cc","ff","dd",NA,"hh",NA,"kk","dd","cc")
```